# What means and how show chart information in Ganglia/RRD Tool?

Tags: linux, charts, rrdtool, rrd, ganglia

I'm using **Ganglia**, which use **RRDTool** as database, to get chart about my servers, but after installing, setting the things up, I notice that **there's a bit of confusion in the way that the data are represented**, at least in the **Ganglia Web** interface.

Let give some examples:
(I delete my IP's address for security reasons)
[image]
What this chart means ? I would like to see the amount of disk in my servers. At the Y axis it gives the idea of Kbytes, is that right ? How should I read this chart ?

Another example, is this one:

[image]

What the Y-axis means ? What is been represented here ? Which metric ? Kb, Mb, Gb ?
I think the chart shouldn't give margin to the imagination, any person should be able to see the chart and know was is been represented here.

So I would like to do that, but how can I correct these lack of information ? (or misunderstanding information)

Comment: If that is in Kb, I'd say it is time for an upgrade!  rrdgraph only takes the data that it is given and plots it on a graph.  You have to look at the data given to rrdupdate to know what rrdgraph will give you.

Comment: but that's the problem, it couldn't be KB, we have TB of disk..

Comment: I assume that you are talking about available disk space?  I would think a line graph would do a better job of showing what you want to see, but that is just my thought.  What does your rrdgraph command look like?  Edit it into the original post for ease of reading.

Comment: @tar.gz, no, total disk mean the disk size.

Comment: i assume the value is being collected via snmp? if so, you'll need to check that SNMP OID and find out what measurement it is collecting at. i'm guessing Gb since you said you have a TB of space. remember that the value is collected as is for rrds. no converstion unless you do something. also i dont know ganglia but it would appear you have the ability to set the vertical label from the following docu - http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ganglia/wiki/ganglia_modular_graph_documentation